# Simplifying Nested Try Catch in Python

Tags: python, pandas, try-catch

I'm stuck on this problem. I'm not necessarily looking for code snippets here, but maybe a higher-level concept of how what I'm trying to do can be engineered.

I have a list of PDF files of different "types". The different type don't contain the same information and are not formatted in the same way. Based on the type of the PDF, I need to extract information from them differently. To do this, I use two Python libraries that allow me to extract data in different ways from the PDF files.

The issue is that I could for instance recognize PDF_1 by looking at index [10] in a Dataframe, while when reading PDF_2, there is no index [10], so I get an IndexError.

Right now, my brute force solution is doing something like below. But this is not doable, because in reality I have many more types of PDF files, and this is extremely unscalable/unreliable

```
for file in os.listdir("all file"):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        content = tab.read_pdf('file/'+file, pages='all', guess=False, stream=True)
        # checks for PDF_1
        try:
            if content[1].columns[10] == 'String identifying PDF 1':
                extract_pdf_1()
                print(file + ' is pdf 1')
            
        # checks for PDF_2
        except:
            try:
                if content.loc[4].str.contains("String identifying PDF 2").all():
                    extract_pdf_2()
                    print(file + ': is pdf 2')
            except:
                print('pdf not recognised')
```

Comment: what are the differences between the types?

Comment: They are formatted completely differently. So during the data extraction process, the output will not be the same.

Comment: I don't know if this is only a mistake here but  the try and except expressions should be on the same level of indentation... In my opinion recognising different types of pdf shouldn't be done in the try catch blocks (especially if you have a lot of different types) You can use if statement and firstly check the length of the array... or find other way to distinguish pdfs

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
def check_pdf_1(content):
    try:
        if content[1].columns[10] == 'String identifying PDF 1':
            return True
    except SpecException as e:
        return False
...
pdf_handlers= {
    1: (check_pdf_1, extract_pdf_1),
    2: (check_pdf_2, extract_pdf_2),
}
...
for file in os.listdir("all file"):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        content = tab.read_pdf('file/' + file, pages='all', guess=False, stream=True)
        for check_pdf, extract_pdf in pdf_handlers.values():
            if check_pdf(content):
                extract_pdf(content)
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create different functions that recognizes each type of pdf, and return "true" or "false" if you find it. In addition you need another function which calls each check-type until it finds a "true" return value. You don't need nested try-check, you can separate them on each function (having all in the same level).

```py
def check1():
    try:
        if content[1].columns[10] == 'String identifying PDF 1':
            extract_pdf_1()
            print(file + ' is pdf 1')
            
    except:
        return False

def check2():
    try:
        if content.loc[4].str.contains("String identifying PDF 2").all():
            extract_pdf_2()
            print(file + ': is pdf 2')
    except:
        return False

def checks(content):
    if (check1(content)):
        return
    if (check2(content)):
        return

for file in os.listdir("all file"):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        content = tab.read_pdf('file/'+file, pages='all', guess=False, stream=True)
        checks(content)
```